# How to get the first part of the "inventory_hostname" in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to get the first part of my `inventory_hostname`.

`server00122.linux.ca.domain.com`

All I want is the `server00122` part.

**My Code:**

```
hostName: "{{ inventory_hostname | basename }}"
```

I use the above code. However, it just gives me the same output.

Answer (score 5):

There is an other [magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) called `inventory_hostname_short`.

Extract from the above link:

> inventory_hostname_short:
>       The short version of inventory_hostname

Comment: This only works for the `inventory_hostname`, not for *any* hostname

Comment: @dokaspar : where did you see a reference about `whateverhostnsme_short`? Op is asking about shortening the name in his inventory. That's exactly the answer and documentation reference I gave. There are no other `*_short` magic vars described there.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the short form of **any** hostname similar to what the Unix command `hostname --short` provides, you can do it with `split()` like this (of course the hard-coded hostname can be replaced with any variable):

```
- name: Print short host name
  debug:
    msg: "{{ 'server00122.linux.ca.domain.com'.split('.')[0] }}"
```

The above task returns:

```
msg: server00122
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `inventory_hostname` use `ansible_hostname`.

That should give you want you need.

Comment: This will not reliably return what you want and will depend on target configuration. Also note that `inventory_hostname[_short]` defined in inventory can be different from `ansible_hostname` gathered from the target.